# Doing the average over a bunch of files

Tags: python, numpy, average, mean

I have 1000 files and each file has 6 columns of information of 1000 points. I would like to do the average of column number 6 for each point in 1000 time steps. I mean for each point I would like to have an average of 1000 time steps and then saving in a text file. The code that I wrote has a problem with understanding the process. It can compute the mean for each point but in the end, it gives me one number.

```
import os
import numpy as np

l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]


maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in l])
l = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]


for i, d in enumerate(l): 
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0]
    #j = np.zeros(1001)

    x = np.mean(a[5])

    #y = np.mean(a[4])

    np.savetxt("foo.txt",x)
```

I will appreciate it if you could give me a favor. Thanks all

Comment: I assume when you say for each point thats equivalent to each file. If it's a csv file, I would start by using pandas, first of all.

Comment: each file has 1000 points that in each point we have 6 columns. I attached one of them here [link](https://gofile.io/?c=cOcV1J) . I have 1000 numbers of this file and I would like to have an average of each point for column number 6.

Comment: You want the column with index = 5 contain the average of 6 columns, right? 0.00166785 to be average of  '0.85809016      -1.88551593       0.00000000      -0.62240386       0.00077418       0.00166785' - this is your first line of data.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question, you are overwriting foo.txt every time, so that's why you only see one number.

open a txt file before the loop, and then just append info:

```
txt_file = open('foo.txt', 'w')
for i, d in enumerate(l):
     txt_file.write(f'{x}\n')
txt_file.close()
```

two things:

1. f"" it's a f-string, available to use from python3.6. If you are using an older version, just format the string as you want.
2. \n means new line, so you write each number in the next line.

Comment: Thanks, I did it but I got an error about NumPy array. `f=open('f1.txt','w')` then `np.savetxt(f, x)` then `f.write(f'{x}\n')` and finally `f.close()`. but I got **Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead**